# Generate .so file by mixing C and C++ for DPI-C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, system-verilog

I have several .c and .cpp files that I want to connect to the System Verilog testbench as a single .so shared object file. The approach I took was using separate .o files compiled into a single .so file, which was then added during vcs compilation with the rest of the SV files.

```
  gcc -w -pipe -fPIC -O -c        file1.c   -o file1.o
  gcc -w -pipe -fPIC -O -c -x c++ file2.cpp -o file2.o
  gcc -shared -o libr.so file1.o file2.o
```

With this approach the C-compilation goes with no errors, but when I am trying to compile the verilog testbench along with the libr.so file, I get 'undefined reference' compile errors. So, it seems like the linking is broken between the c and c++ files, and the vcs compilation fails. The c++ file is written in the c-style, so when I change the extension of file2.cpp to file2.c, everything compiles and works as expected.

The interface between the SV and DPI is through the .c file. That is, SV calls a function from .c file which then calls another function from the .cpp file. The error is "undefine reference" to the function in the .cpp file.

I found several examples that show how to compile c OR c++ files into the system verilog testbench, but could not find examples that combine c and c++. So, the problem seems to be related to mixing c and c++ files.

Is mixing even supported in Synopsys VCS compiler? Are my compile commands from above correct? Any ideas for what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call a c++ function from 'c' the c++ function must be declared with the `extern "C"` binding, for example:

```
extern "C" void foo(int);
```

or

```
extern "C" {
   void bar();
}
```

Now you can call `foo(3)` or `bar()` from 'c'

Also, you do not need an extra 'c' file to define DPI functions in system verilog. You can still use `extern "C"` in your c++ files and use those functions for DPI.

Comment: In an extreme case one could do `extern "C"{ #include"cheader.h" }`, I think.

Comment: @Serge so, you are saying that the content of every .cpp file that I use should be enclosed in `extern "C"{}` ?

Comment: No, I did not say anything about **all** c++ context. Only function definitions in c++ files which are accessed by DPI or from a 'c' program must be enclosed int the *extern "C" {...}*. All normal c++ function names are mangled in the object files. C function names are not mangled. *extern C* prevents them from mangling by c++.

Comment: @Serge you are right - it would not make sense to enclose all the files in that. However, when I call foo1(), which calls foo2(), which calls foo3(), where they come from .c, .cpp, .cpp files, respectively, then the compiler complains about foo3() being undefined. So, enclosing seems to be necessary. There must be something I am missing...

Comment: you need to provide an example.  'foo1' is in a 'c' file and is compiled by a 'c' compiler, it can call 'foo2' only if foo2 is declared as external "C" in the cpp file. 'foo2' in its turn can call *any* c++ function with or without extern "C". If you want to call a 'c' funciton from 'c++', you need to declare its proptotype as extern "C" as well. If you are missing symbols in this scheme, it only means that you do not provide all the files needed for linking.